# Having a runtime error with java program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AvgTime {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SETINEL = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int count;
        int runnerID;
        for(runnerID = in.nextInt() ; runnerID != 0 ; runnerID = in.nextInt())
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(count = 1 ; count <= 8 ; count++)
            {
                double runnerTime = in.nextDouble();
                sum += runnerTime;
            }
            double average = sum / count;
            System.out.println("ID: " + runnerID + "Average: " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

trying to input values

```
2346789
90
80.5
95
100
90
88.5
78
94.5
2347890
100
90
75.5
80
75.5
89
78.5
80
0
```

and I get

```
ID: 2346789Average: 79.61111111111111
ID: 2347890Average: 74.27777777777777
```

when I should get `89.5625` and `83.5625`

Comment: Do you mean `runnerID` by `runnersID`?

Comment: yes sorry typo there in my comment it should be runnerID

Comment: The loop `for(count = 1 ; count <=8 ; count++) ;` seems meaningless. It won't even repeat `sum = runnerTime ;` 8 times, while repeating it is also meaningless.

Comment: Don't you want sum = sum + runnerTime;

Comment: I am asked to to do this problem with nested loops so thats why i put that in there

Comment: Response to Edit #4: `average = sum / count`, but what is value of `count` after loop `for(count = 1 ; count <= 8 ; count++)`? Oh yeah, **9**. If it was 8, the loop wouldn't have ended. If you hardcode the number of iterations, why not hardcode the divisor? `average = sum / 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put semicolons after `for` loop to make this behave in unexpected way. Remove them.

You will also have to fix problem with the inner loop, where you read the time only once while I guess it should be read 8 times and added. Also don't forget to initialize `sum` for each runners.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AvgTime {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SETINEL = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int count;
        int runnerID;
        for(runnerID = in.nextInt() ; runnerID != 0 ; runnerID = in.nextInt())
        {
            sum = 0;
            for(count = 0 ; count < 8 ; count++)
            {
                double runnerTime = in.nextDouble();
                sum += runnerTime;
            }
            double average = sum / count;
            System.out.println("ID: " + runnerID + "Average: " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have ran this program ran the inputs given but the output was a little off  i shown the input and output desired now in my original question

Comment: @JeremyLodge It is because `count` will be 9 after the loop with condition `count <= 8`. Updated my answer.

Comment: alright that now works perfectly, thanks very much MikeCat  saved me from a all nighter